# How to find the number of rows changed by an UPDATE statement in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

Imagine the following table:

```
id | name | family
---+------+--------
 0 | John | Smith
 1 | Mary | Winters
 2 | John | Doe
```

and now the following statement:

```
UPDATE t SET name = 'John' WHERE id = 0;
```

This statement in fact would update nothing – as it reflects what already is there. Now all the blogs, manuals and whatsnots said to check `SQL%ROWCOUNT` for the number of updated rows. Doing that returns `1` (*affected* rows – i.e. those the `WHERE` clause did match). Let's have another one:

```
UPDATE t SET family = 'Smith' WHERE name = 'John';
```

De facto, that would only change the row with id=2, so I want something stating "1 row updated" – but `SQL%ROWCOUNT` gives us `2` (again, rows *affected*).

So here comes the final question: What gives the number of rows ***changed***?

Comment: You'll have to do it by modifying your query to exlude rows that don't need updating to be identical. `UPDATE t SET family = 'Smith' WHERE name = 'John' and family<>'Smith'` ;

Comment: @Phil that may do in the simple example here. But imagine a table with 100 columns where 80 are in the `SET` part. Your approach is hard to maintain with that. Though it's of course true ;)

Comment: You can create after update, insert,delete for each row triggers that log the before and after changes to a log table when a column was actually changed. However, depending on the volume of changes in your application you could cause your application to not scale very well. Ultimately preventing this kind of change is a design choice and you need to look at the trade off for performance.

Comment: @Gandolf989 thanks. Yes, that's why this approach is not a good idea with huge amounts of data involved. I was rather looking for a pendant to `SQL%ROWNUM` – i.e. a variable holding the number of changed records.

Comment: There is no great way to do that. How much work are you going to do to see if a CLOB or a BLOB has changed? It seems to me that you should just not make this a requirement, since it will likely cause you to add unnecessary complexity to your application.

Comment: @Gandolf989 I don't want the *details* – I just want the *number of rows changed.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you issue an update statement on your table that effectively updates the data to the same value that is already there, then the database does update the row, so the `SQL%ROWCOUNT` is accurate even though the new value is the same as the old value.

You can use a flashback versions query to see that database has indeed updated the record:

```
select t.*
     , VERSIONS_OPERATION
     , VERSIONS_STARTTIME
     , VERSIONS_ENDTIME
     , VERSIONS_XID
  from t
  versions between timestamp systimestamp - interval '10' minute and systimestamp
 where id = 0;

UPDATE t SET name = 'John' WHERE id = 0;
commit;

select t.*
     , VERSIONS_OPERATION
     , VERSIONS_STARTTIME
     , VERSIONS_ENDTIME
     , VERSIONS_XID
  from t
  versions between timestamp systimestamp - interval '10' minute and systimestamp
 where id = 0;
```

In the first query above there will likely be only one row returned for `ID=0`.  Then after issuing and committing an update against `ID=0` the second time the flashback versions query is run you should get back two records, one for the original record where the `VERSIONS_ENDTIME` column has been filled in and one for the new version of the record showing that the operation against it was an `U`pdate and that the record has a `VERSIONS_STARTTIME` equal to the end time of the original record.

The only way to prevent records from being updated with the same values is either with an appropriate predicate in the where clause, or in an on update for each row trigger that rejects the change by raising an error.

Comment: Good reasoning, thanks. Not the answer I *wanted* to hear, though – but I didn't expect an "easy solution" anyway (still, wouldn't have been the first time an SE answer surprised me ;) I'll accept that for now – until the one with the surprise-answer turns up :)